# Codeigniter allow accented letters in URL

Tags: url, codeigniter, uri, diacritics

So you have this preference in CodeIgniter:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

How do you change this so that é, à, è, ç etc. are allowed? I need this for my search url's.

Comment: So I just type 'Unicode' in there? I really want to be careful here because some characters should never be allowed in the url

Comment: No, when you are searching, those "accented letters" are called Unicode. Check out [Wikipedi](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Unicode) and [Joel's article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add any characters you want to use in your `permitted_uri_chars` list.

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-éàèç';`